# What is the replacement for "metadataLoaded" in JSONModel?

Tags: sapui5

In `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`, there is a [`metadataLoaded`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#event:metadataLoaded) method which I can use it like this:

```js
this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then( function() {
    var sObjectPath = this.getModel().createKey("/", {
        ID :  sObjectId
    });
    this._bindView("/" + sObjectPath);
}.bind(this));
```

[`JSONModel`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html) doesn't seem to have a corresponding method since there is no *service metadata* concept in client-side models. So is there any other work around?

I tried `attachRequestCompleted`. It's not working as expected:

```js
function bindview() {
    that._bindView(sObjectId);
}
this.getModel().attachRequestCompleted(bindview);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly said, there is no metadata. But for Json model why do you want to wait for any event? You can directly bind the view.

Comment: Sometimes I found that the API that get the JSON Model is pending when I call bindview in _onObjectMatched.  (`this.getRouter().getRoute("object").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);`)

Answer (score 0):

`attachRequestCompleted` only fires once when model is loaded, So I fix this problem in this way:

```
jsonModelLoaded: false,

_onObjectMatched : function (oEvent) {
    if(this.jsonModelLoaded) {
        this._bindView(sObjectId);
    }

    function bindview() {
        that.jsonModelLoaded = true;
        that._bindView(sObjectId);
    }
    this.getModel().attachRequestCompleted(bindview);
}
```

another not documented solution is using `this.getModel().attachRequestCompleted().pSequentialImportCo‌​mpleted.then()`

Related question here: [Why metadataLoaded can be fired multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670186/why-metadataloaded-can-be-fired-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.64<sup>1</sup>, `JSONModel` returns a promise when [`loadData`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel#methods/loadData) or [`dataLoaded`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel#methods/dataLoaded) is called. For example:

```js
_onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
  const myJSONModel = this.getView().getModel();
  const sObjectId = /*...*/;
  myJSONModel.dataLoaded().then(() => this._bindView(sObjectId));
},
```

Unlike `v2ODatamodel.metadataLoaded()2`, the promise here **actually rejects** if the request fails.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Commit: [`bd4e2fc`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/bd4e2fc76cf736e3b40fa821953a60ef2e71fb32)

<sup>2</sup> The promise returned from `metadataLoaded()` never rejects even if loading the metadata document failed. However, [since 1.79](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/08dc44183fc6a36135ed804461c94d7ee0f24535#diff-f5079478d1bc7dcc6a758751c1c50c06), apps can pass `true` as an argument to get a catch-able promise: `metadataLoaded(true)`.</sup>