# Why metadataLoaded can be fired multiple times?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Related question: [What is the replacement for metadataLoaded in JSON model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772916/what-is-the-replacement-for-metadataloaded-in-json-model)

---

When I use [metadataLoaded](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#event:metadataLoaded) in `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`, Everytime `_onObjectMatched` is called , `metadataLoaded` can also be fired.:

`this.getRouter().getRoute("object").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);`

```
            _onObjectMatched : function (oEvent) {
                var sObjectId =  oEvent.getParameter("arguments").objectId;
                this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then( function() {
                    //fired every time
                    this._bindView(sObjectId);
                }.bind(this));
            },
```

---

But when I use `RequestCompleted` in `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel`, `RequestCompleted` only fired once when the request data loaded.

```
this.getModel().attachRequestCompleted(function() {
    //fired only once 
    this._bindView(sObjectId);
});
```

I am curious why? I think metadata should also be loaded only once?

---

Update:

[image: console]

Actually, I have already find that metadataLoaded returns a promise (I should have known that when I saw `then()`), but just as @Nabi point out, I am not familiar with promise. I should have dig deeper before I ask this question.

The aim of both question is to find an elegant and official replacement for `metadataLoaded` in JSON model, should I combine them or sth.?

Comment: why was the question downvoted? Doing this without a comment is not fair.

Comment: Obviously because the question and the related one doe not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_onObjectMatched()` is called everytime your route matches. In there you always call `this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then(...)` while `metadataLoadad()` returns a promise which resolves when the metadata is loaded (in the past or in the future). This happens everytime because `this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then(...)` is called everytime.

Probably it's a good idea to have a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), I'm sure you'll get the idea. In fact, make sure you understand the difference between events and Promises...

Comment: Thanks, I use `this.getModel().attachRequestCompleted().pSequentialImportCompleted.then()`, and it solved my problem. (Although I did not find `pSequentialImportCompleted` in doc, just know it is returns a promise...

Comment: Ok... Then be aware that you are using some private API which might cause issues in future.. ;-)

Comment: @TinaChen `pSequentialImportCompleted` is still kept in the source code but if anyone is using v1.64 or above, the public API `dataLoaded` should be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61879725/5846045